# TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined after call following function in another file

Tags: node.js

I have created a function in my new file and get data from DB and return the query result in res. status(200).json this code showing error TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

for ex:-

```
 exports.chkMaintenanceMode = function (req, res, next) {
            Configuration.findOne({meta_group: 'maintenance_mode'}).exec(function (err, result) {
                if(err) return false;
                if(result){
                  console.log("result", result)
                  return res.status(200).json({
                    data: result,
                    reply: "",
                    meta: req.phoneMeta
                  });
                }
            });
      }
```

this function used in another file server.js
for ex:-

const maintenance = require('./maintenance.js').chkMaintenanceMode();
console.log("maintenance", maintenance)

Comment: you have to pass chkMaintenanceMode to specific express route in order to access req and res functions

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your chkMaintenanceMode method to specific express route in order to access req and res functions.

sample code in server.js:

```
    const maintenance = require('./maintenance.js');
    const express=require('express');
const app=express();
    
    app.get("/",maintenance.chkMaintenanceMode);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I don't want to be a route, I just want to send a flag to this function and directly use that to the server.js

Comment: return res.status(200).json({
                    data: result,
                    reply: "",
                    meta: req.phoneMeta
                  });

you cannot use this code if you are not willing to put it in the router

Comment: because req,res,next are provided by express to its routes

Comment: exports.chkMaintenanceMode = function () {
            Configuration.findOne({meta_group: 'maintenance_mode'}).exec(function (err, result) {
                if(err) return false;
                if(result){
                  console.log("result", result)
                
                }
            });
      }

you can use this function if you want to log the result only